# OpenCV - getting the slider to update its position during video playback

Tags: c++, c, video, opencv, slider

I've picked up 'Learning OpenCV' and have been trying some of the code examples/exercises. In this code snippet, I want to get the slider to update its position with each video frame change, but for some reason it won't work (the picture freezes with the following code):

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"

int g_slider_position = 0;
CvCapture* g_capture = NULL;

void onTrackbarSlide(int pos)
{
    cvSetCaptureProperty(g_capture, CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, pos);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cvNamedWindow("The Tom 'n Jerry Show", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    g_capture = cvCreateFileCapture(argv[1]);
    int frames = (int) cvGetCaptureProperty(
        g_capture, 
        CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT
        );

    if (frames != 0)
    {
        cvCreateTrackbar(
            "Position",
            "The Tom 'n Jerry Show",
            &g_slider_position,
            frames,
            onTrackbarSlide
            );
    }

    IplImage* frame;

    while (1)
    {
        frame = cvQueryFrame(g_capture);
        if (!frame) 
            break;

        cvSetTrackbarPos(
            "Position", 
            "The Tom 'n Jerry Show",
            ++g_slider_position
            );

        cvShowImage("The Tom 'n Jerry Show", frame);
        char c = cvWaitKey(33);
        if (c == 27)
            break;
    }

    cvReleaseCapture(&g_capture);
    cvDestroyWindow("The Tom 'n Jerry Show");

    return 0;
}
```

Any idea how to get the slider and video to work as intended?

Comment: Does the picture freeze or the whole application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
This is the actual working code



// PROGRAM TO ADD A UPDATING TRACKBAR TO A VIDEO

#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>


int g_slider_position = 0;
CvCapture* video_capture = NULL;

void onTrackbarSlide(int current_frame)
{
    current_frame = g_slider_position;
    cvSetCaptureProperty(video_capture,CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,current_frame);
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    cvNamedWindow( "Video", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    video_capture = cvCreateFileCapture( "Crowdy.avi");
    int no_of_frames = (int) cvGetCaptureProperty(video_capture,CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
    if( no_of_frames!= 0 ) 
    {
        cvCreateTrackbar("Slider","Video",&g_slider_position,no_of_frames,onTrackbarSlide);
    }

    IplImage* frame;

    while(1) 
    {
        frame = cvQueryFrame( video_capture );
        if( !frame ) break;
        cvShowImage( "Video", frame );
        cvSetTrackbarPos("Slider","Video",++g_slider_position);
        char c = cvWaitKey(33);
        if( c == 27 ) break;
    }
    cvReleaseCapture( &video_capture );
    cvDestroyWindow( "Video" );

    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You are incrementing g_slider_position twice in the code, so it will increment beyond its limit (set in `cvCreateTrackbar` as `frames`).  This is likely causing your picture to freeze.

To fix, change this

```
    g_slider_position++;
    cvSetTrackbarPos(
        "Position", 
        "The Tom 'n Jerry Show",
        ++g_slider_position
        );
```

to

```
    cvSetTrackbarPos(
        "Position", 
        "The Tom 'n Jerry Show",
        ++g_slider_position
        );
```

---

Accounting for the edited code, I would check that OpenCV is properly reading the number of frames from your file.  Look at Learning OpenCV's Chapter 2, example 2.3 for a method of generically retrieving the number of frames from your AVI (if that is what you are using).

In your code above, if the number of frames is 0, the trackbar is not created but the code still enters a loop that attempts to update the trackbar position (if it finds a frame).  I would use this instead:

```
if (frames != 0)
{
    cvCreateTrackbar(
        "Position",
        "The Tom 'n Jerry Show",
        &g_slider_position,
        frames,
        onTrackbarSlide
        );
} 
else
{
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I had actually misquoted my code. The code that I want corrected does not have the `++g_slider_position;` statement. I have edited the above question; it gives the same problem as described initially.

Comment: Thanks Seth. It is apparently finding the total number of frames correctly, though your edit obviously made the code much more robust. Unfortunately the problem still occurs (the video freezes but the trackbar updates itself properly). Btw, yes, this is an avi.

Comment: @Kristian - I see.  I mis-interpreted what was freezing here.  The fact that the trackbar continues to update itself suggests that there is an issue with your decoder.  Can you convert the avi file to raw and try again?  The conversion can be accomplished by running 'mencoder in.avi -ovc raw -vf format=i420 -o out.avi'

Answer (score 3):

This seems a bit complicated to me. I used the `cvGetCaptureProperty(g_capture, CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)` call to retrieve the current frame and used this to update the slider.

The callback function is then used just to change the position within g_capture.

So the call back is:

```
//Call back for slider bar
void onTrackbarSlide(int pos) {
    cvSetCaptureProperty(g_capture, CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, pos);
}
```

And the loop is:

```
IplImage* frame; //Frame grabbed from video
while(1) {
    frame = cvQueryFrame( g_capture );
    if (!frame ) break;
    cvShowImage( "Example2", frame );

    g_frame_count = (int) cvGetCaptureProperty(g_capture, CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES);

    cvSetTrackbarPos("Position","Example2", g_frame_count);

    char c = cvWaitKey(33);
    if ( c == 27 ) break;
}
```

Where the `g_` variables are global.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the solution below.

change this

```
void onTrackbarSlide(int pos)
{
    cvSetCaptureProperty(g_capture, CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, pos);
}
```

to

```
void onTrackbarSlide( int pos )
{
    if( pos > g_slider_position + 1 )
    cvSetCaptureProperty( 
        g_capture, 
        CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 
        pos);
}
```

and also change this

```
cvSetTrackbarPos(
            "Position", 
            "The Tom 'n Jerry Show",
            ++g_slider_position
            );
```

to

```
cvSetTrackbarPos(
            "Position", 
            "The Tom 'n Jerry Show",
            g_slider_position + 1
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi I have simlar code and I did the following:

```
void onTrackbarSlide(int pos)
{
if(pos > g_lastPosition+1 || pos < g_lastPosition)
cvSetCaptureProperty(g_capture,CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,pos);
g_lastPosition = pos;
}
```

.............

```
while(1)
{
frame = cvQueryFrame( g_capture );
if( !frame ) break;
cvShowImage( "Example3", frame );
cvSetTrackbarPos("Position", "Example3", g_slider_position+1);
char c = cvWaitKey(33);
if( c == 27 ) break;
}
```

So you can grab the slide bar to any direction , I hope this can help

Answer (score 1):

OK I finally solved this problem of updating the slider 
and also if you want to move the slider the video will update 
there is no problem of picture freezing now

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include<cv.h>
#include<cxcore.h>
#include<highgui.h>

int g_slider_position = 0;
CvCapture* g_capture = NULL;
int count=0;              //initiate a global counter



void onTrackbarSlide( int pos )
{// if you are moving the slider for more than two frames then this loop will initiate      to
 // to update the video
    if(pos>count+2 || pos<count-2){
    cvSetCaptureProperty( 
        g_capture, 
        CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 
        pos);}
    count=pos;
}
int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //int count=0;
    cvNamedWindow("Example3",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    g_capture=cvCreateFileCapture("video.avi");
    int frames = (int) cvGetCaptureProperty(
        g_capture,
        CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT
        );
    if(frames!= 0) {
        cvCreateTrackbar(
            "Position",
            "Example3",
            &g_slider_position,
            frames,
            onTrackbarSlide
            );
    }
    IplImage* frame;
    while (1)
    {
        count++;  // the counter will move along with the frame
        frame = cvQueryFrame( g_capture );
        if (!frame) break;
        cvShowImage ("Example3", frame);
        cvSetTrackbarPos("Position", "Example3", g_slider_position+1);
        char c = cvWaitKey(33);
        if(c==27) break;
    }

    cvReleaseCapture(&g_capture);
    cvDestroyWindow("Example3");
    return 0;
}
```

ok now what i have done is that i have created a global counter which will be updated  alongside with the frames

now when we use the slider with the mouse to a different position then in  onTrackbarSlider routine the if loop will be initiated and it will set the video to the new position