# OpenCV TrackbarSlider strange behaviour

Tags: c++, opencv, slider, trackbar

Hi i'm going through the book "learning openCV" in an early example I get problems.

I would like to build a little video-player, that can go a single frame forwards and backwards, can jump to a specific frame by entering the frame number and browse through frames by a TrackbarSlider.
The TrackbarSlider should also show the present frame number.

At the moment I'm only implementing the TrackbarSlider.
I want it to count up the frames of my video and if I click it at a specific position video should go on playing from that position.

Unfortunately this doesn't happen.
If I click anywhere in the slider, the video starts from frame 0 slider is also reset to this position.

Aswell I don't understand why console shows me that frame number is reset to 0 after a slide occured.
(I know that the movement of the slider position from one frame to the next causes a callback to onTrackbarSlide())

```cpp
// Example2-3.cpp : Definiert den Einstiegspunkt für die Konsolenanwendung.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include <iostream>

int g_slider_position = 0;
CvCapture* g_capture = NULL;

void onTrackbarSlide(int pos)
{
    cout << "TrackbarSlide occured " << endl;
    cout << "pos: " << pos << endl;
    cvSetCaptureProperty(g_capture, CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, pos);
    cout << "Framenumber after SetTrackbarPos ";
    cout << cvGetCaptureProperty(g_capture,CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES) << endl; 

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    cout << "TEST" << endl;
    cvNamedWindow("Example3", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    g_capture = cvCreateFileCapture("test.avi");
    //g_capture = cvCreateFileCapture( argv[1]);
    int frames = (int) cvGetCaptureProperty(g_capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
    if (frames != 0)
    {
        cvCreateTrackbar( "Position","Example3",&g_slider_position,frames,onTrackbarSlide);
    }
    IplImage* frame;
    while(1)
    {

        frame = cvQueryFrame(g_capture);

        if(!frame) break;
        cvShowImage("Example3",frame);

        char c = cvWaitKey(250);
        if(c==27) break;

        cout << "Framenumber ";
        cout << cvGetCaptureProperty(g_capture,CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES) << endl; 

        cvSetTrackbarPos("Position", "Example3", cvGetCaptureProperty(g_capture,CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES));


    }
    cvReleaseCapture(&g_capture);
    cvDestroyWindow("Example3");
    return 0;
}
```

Thats what i get from the console:
console output: http://s14.directupload.net/images/120422/9cdu7mhk.png

forgot to mention... following site could of interest: [OpenCV - getting the slider to update its position during video playback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047913/opencv-getting-the-slider-to-update-its-position-during-video-playback)

Thank You
eujono

Answer (score 0):

Der Fehler liegt in der Zeile

```
cvSetTrackbarPos("Position", "Example3", 
                 cvGetCaptureProperty(g_capture,CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES));
```

Sie setzt das Video immer wieder auf den Anfang zurück.
Klammere die Zeile aus und das Video läßt sich über die TrackBar 
einwandfrei bewegen.

Möchte man, dass der Scrollbalken mitläuft, muss die Nullsetzung abgefangen werden.
z.B.:

```
int FramePos = cvGetCaptureProperty(g_capture,CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES);
if (FramePos!=0) 
  cvSetTrackbarPos("Position", "Example3",FramePos);
```

---

The mistake is in the line

```
cvSetTrackbarPos("Position", "Example3", 
                 cvGetCaptureProperty(g_capture,CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES));
```

The command resets the video to the beginning.
Mark that line as a comment and it works fine.

You want that Trackbar runs, the zeroing can be intercepted.
e.g.:

```
int FramePos = cvGetCaptureProperty(g_capture,CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES);
if (FramePos!=0) 
  cvSetTrackbarPos("Position", "Example3",FramePos);
```